# Symfony2 Many to one - one to many without join table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have "Project" entity which can have several Benefits, while a benefit belongs to just one Project:
To me it seems a many to one - one to many relationship.
I followed the indication [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

The Project entity is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects")
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\oneToMany(targetEntity="Benefit", mappedBy="project")
     */
    protected $benefits;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->benefits = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // other stuff

    /**
     * Add benefits
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefits
     * @return Project
     */
    public function addBenefit(\AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefits)
    {
        $this->benefits[] = $benefits;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove benefits
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefits
     */
    public function removeBenefit(\AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefits)
    {
        $this->benefits->removeElement($benefits);
    }

    /**
     * Get benefits
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getBenefits()
    {
        return $this->benefits;
    }
}
```

The benefit entity is:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\BenefitRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="benefits")
 */
class Benefit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    // Other relevant fields

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", inversedBy="benefits")
     */
    protected $project;
```

In my controller I was hoping to do:

```
$project = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->findOneById(3);

$benefit = new Benefit();
// set some fields for the new Benefit
$benefit->setProject($project);
$em->persist($benefit);
```

and I was hoping to see the benefits as a collection inside the project entity doing:

```
$benefits = $project->getBenefits();
```

But it did not work, so I explicitely did:

```
$project->addBenefit($benefit);
$em->persist($project);
$benefits = $project->getBenefits();
```

And I indeed see new the newly created Benefit inside the collection inside project. The problem is that if I rerun this and add a new benefit to the same project, I just get the last one. Of course if in the same portion of code I create 2 benefits and add both, I have a collection of 2, but that's not what I want. On the Benefit side everything is ok: each new Benefit is persisted, all of them correctly pointing to the same Project.

What am I missing?

EDIT:

Here are the steps I make/stuff I checked:

The DB is in sync with the current entity metadata.
The updated Project entity is:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Project.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="projects")
 */
class Project
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\oneToMany(targetEntity="Benefit", mappedBy="project", cascade="persist")
     */
    protected $benefits;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->benefits = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    // Other irrelevant fields

    /**
     * Add benefits
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefit
     * @return Project
     */
    public function addBenefit(\AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefit)
    {
        $this->benefits[] = $benefit;
        $benefit->setProject($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove benefits
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefits
     */
    public function removeBenefit(\AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefits)
    {
        $this->benefits->removeElement($benefits);
    }

    /**
     * Get benefits
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getBenefits()
    {
        return $this->benefits;
    }
}
```

Note that the removeBenefit is probably not properly implemented, but for the moment it's not relevant.

I clean the Benefit table.

I create a new benefit and attach to the a Project:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$project = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->findOneById(3);
$benefit = new Benefit();
$benefit->setName('Name of the benefit');
// here I set other irrelevant fields 
$project->addBenefit($benefit);

$em->persist($project);
$em->flush();
```

The Benefit gets properly persisted to DB. It properly links to the Project:

[image]

I then comment all the code in the controller and simply perform:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$project = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Project')->findOneById(3);
$benefits = $project->getBenefits();
return $this->render('testBenefits.html.twig', array(
        'benefits' => $benefits, 'project' => $project));
```

If I dump $project I get:

[image]

And of course if I dump $benefits I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting project in your benefit class.

```
public function addBenefit(\AppBundle\Entity\Benefit $benefit)
{
    $this->benefits[] = $benefit;
    $benefit->setProject($this);  // Add this
    return $this;
}
```

Noticed that I also changed your argument from benefits to benefit as addBenefit deals with one benefit object at a time.

Comment: Thank you @Cerad, I wrongly trusted the automatic getters and setters. This indeed solves the issue of having to set both references manually. I just set parent->child, and it automatically creates the child->parent. I also found that including the cascade="persist" when I save the parent it also saves the child, which is nice...but still I don't get all the children of a parent. It's like the getBenefits() method is not properly implemented :(

Comment: Check your database.  You probably have some older benefits records whose project_id column is null.  Delete those and all should be well going forward.  It's important to understand that the entities themselves are just plain php objects and know nothing about the ORM mappings.  So it's up to you to make sure the relations are set properly.  It really does work.  I promise.  Just need to get over the learning hump.  The doctrine manual is helpful: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: And don't forget to call $em->flush() after adding benefits (or making any other change).

Comment: I clean DB every time I make a change. Benefit table is empty. I retrieve the project. I create and add the benefit to the project. I persist project and flush. All good (the benefit is in the DB with the project_id properly set). If I now call the getBenefits I have an empty array collection :( . The problem is there.

Comment: It's like the getBenefits worked only if I add one or many benefits and call the getBenefits straight away (in runtime, not getting the data from DB)

Comment: Update your question with the current relevant code. $project = ...->find(42); echo count($project->getBenefits()); should work as expected assuming you have benefit records with a project_id of 42 in your database.  Maybe make a command object and test from the command line until you get things working.  Might be something else going on.

Comment: Just edited making clear all the steps taken. No idea how to create a command but this is the equivalent, the controller is really skinny and now you can see the dumps of all the relevant entities. Hope you can spot the mistake I'm missing...

Comment: Any files under Resources/config/doctrine?

Comment: in "app\Resources" I have no directory called doctrine. In "src\AppBundle\Resources\config" I have no doctrine directory either. I really appreciate the time you are dedicating to find out what's going on here!

Comment: Maybe here is something helpful: reading here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html in section 8.2 I read $user->getAuthoredComments()->add($newComment); instead of what I was expecting $user->add($newComment); . I tried it but it gives me the following error "Attempted to call method "addBenefit" on class "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection"."

Comment: Re my last comment I made a mistake, the proper call would be: $project->getBenefits()->add($benefit); . The code does not give me any error, I have to set both sides manually again, but in any case I don't solve the issue of the empty array collection.

Comment: The two are equivalent.  You have some other code that is interfering or you are misinterpreting the results. Divert for a bit and build a command: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html It's something you will want to know how to do anyways.  Then work through the product/category example in the book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Comment: Ok, I made a huge step forward. I created new classes Father and Child from scratch, with just a "name" field and the links between them. Same story. BUT I made it work: if I create a form based on the entities the form properly shows the data, while the father is still "on paper" with an empty array collection. Shall I post an answer? I don't think it's the way it should work, as when I call the getChildren() I have empty, but the form make it work :/

Comment: How exactly do you know that getChildren is empty?  I think you may be going down a rabbit hole here.  Try die(count($parent->getChildren());

Comment: OMG you are right...it's simply Symfony's debugger that does not show me the elements, but if I loop on children I can get each child. It's been a nightmare and I really thank you for your time. Btw: could you give me a last help on how to implement the "removeBenefit"?

Comment: removeElement http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.1/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

Comment: Thank you. Can you update your answer saying something like "the problem is of the debugger which does not show all the entities" or something like that? I'd therefore accept the answer, and it'd more useful for future reference for other users.